Парсинг данных с файла
Мне необходимо сделать правильное чтение данных из txt-файла и по полученным данным построить один график для необходимого спектра(который выберет пользователь). В txt-файле несколько спектров, до 9 максимум. TXT-файл имеет такое наполнение:


Длина волны, нм % пропускания
Спектр 0 
400,0   36,3558
401,0   35,6798
-- --
1095,2  60,4672
1096,2  60,6842    
Спектр 3 
400,0   16,0264
401,0   15,0475



Моя проблема в том, что не читаются правильно/не воспринимаются данные и дальше не происходит чтение для построения графика. В консоли пишет, что массив полученных данных 0, 0 полученных данных, ошибка парсинга и т.д. Мой код parseFile.jsx:


    export default function parseFile(fileContent) {
  const spectra = fileContent
    .split('Спектр ')
    .slice(1)
    .map((spectrumData) => {
      const lines = spectrumData.trim().split('\n');
      const spectrumName = `Спектр ${lines.shift()}`;
      const data = lines.map(line => {
        const [wavelength, coefficient] = line.split(/\s+/).map(value => parseFloat(value.replace(',', '.')));
        return { wavelength, coefficient };
      });
      return { name: spectrumName, data };
    });
  
  console.log("Parsed Spectra:", spectra);
  return spectra.slice(0, 9); 
 }



Пробовал еще добавить конвертер файла, данные из файла все также не читаются. Код convertFile.jsx:


  export default function convertFile(fileContent) {
  if (typeof fileContent !== 'string') {
    console.error("Invalid file content type:", typeof fileContent);
    return '';
  }

    
  const lines = fileContent.split('\n');
  const convertedLines = [];
  let currentSpectrum = null;

  lines.forEach((line) => {
    const trimmedLine = line.trim();
    if (/^Спектр\s*\d+/i.test(trimmedLine)) {
      currentSpectrum = trimmedLine;
      convertedLines.push(trimmedLine);
    } else if (currentSpectrum && trimmedLine.includes(',')) {
      const [wavelength, coefficient] = trimmedLine.split(',').map(Number);
      if (!isNaN(wavelength) && !isNaN(coefficient) && wavelength >= 400 && wavelength <= 1100) {
        convertedLines.push(`${wavelength},${coefficient}`);
      }
    }
  });

  const convertedContent = convertedLines.join('\n');
  console.log("Converted Content:", convertedContent);
  return convertedContent;
}



Если нужен какой-либо еще файл, то напишите. Вот структура проекта:

├── /src
│ ├── /components
│ │ ├── FileUpload.jsx
│ │ ├── Chart.jsx
│ │ ├── Header.jsx
│ │ ├── SpectrumSelector.jsx
│ │ ├── WelcomePage.jsx
│ ├── /styles
│ │ ├── FileUpload.css
│ │ ├── Chart.css
│ │ ├── Header.css
│ │ ├── SpectrumSelector.css
│ │ ├── WelcomePage.css
│ ├── /utils
│ │ └── parseFile.jsx
│ │ └── convertFile.jsx
│ ├── App.jsx
│ ├── main.jsx
│ ├── index.css
│ ├── App.css

Загружаемый файл обрабатывается в файлах App и FileUpload. FileUpload:


    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import parseFile from '../utils/parseFile';
import convertFile from '../utils/convertFile';
import { useState } from 'react';
import '../styles/FileUpload.css';

function FileUpload({ onFileData }) {
  const [fileName, setFileName] = useState("Файл не выбран");
  const [inputKey, setInputKey] = useState(Date.now()); // Уникальный ключ для input

  const handleFileChange = (event) => {
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  if (file) {
    setFileName(file.name);
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e) => {
      try {
        const buffer = e.target.result;
        if (!(buffer instanceof ArrayBuffer)) {
          throw new Error("Invalid buffer type"); // Если не ArrayBuffer, вызываем ошибку
        }

        let decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
        let text = decoder.decode(buffer);
        
        if (!/[А-Яа-яЁё]/.test(text)) { 
          decoder = new TextDecoder("windows-1251");
          text = decoder.decode(buffer);
        }

        console.log("File Content:", text);
        const convertedContent = convertFile(text);
        const parsedData = parseFile(convertedContent);
        onFileData(parsedData);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error parsing file:', error);
        alert('Ошибка при парсинге файла. Пожалуйста, проверьте формат.');
        onFileData(null);
      }
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  }
};

  const handleReset = () => {
    setFileName("Файл не выбран");
    onFileData(null); // Передаем пустое значение для сброса графика
    setInputKey(Date.now()); // Обновляем ключ для сброса input
  };

  return (
    <div className="file-upload-container">
      <label htmlFor="file-upload" className="file-label">{fileName}</label>
      <input 
        key={inputKey}
        id="file-upload" 
        type="file" 
        accept=".txt" 
        onChange={handleFileChange} 
        className="file-input" 
      />
      {fileName !== "Файл не выбран" && (
        <button className="reset-button" onClick={handleReset}>
          Очистить график
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

FileUpload.propTypes = {
  onFileData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default FileUpload;



и App


import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState } from 'react';
import WelcomePage from './components/WelcomePage';
import FileUpload from './components/FileUpload';
import Chart from './components/Chart';
import Header from './components/Header';
import convertFile from './utils/convertFile';
import parseFile from './utils/parseFile';
import SpectrumSelector from './components/SpectrumSelector';
import './App.css';
import './styles/FileUpload.css';

function App() {
  const [data, setSpectraData] = useState(null);
  const [selectedSpectrum, setSelectedSpectrum] = useState(null);

  const handleFileData = (fileContent) => {
    // Преобразуем данные перед парсингом
    const convertedContent = convertFile(fileContent);
    const parsedData = parseFile(convertedContent); // Парсим преобразованный файл

    console.log('Parsed Data:', parsedData); // Выводим результат в консоль для проверки
    setSpectraData(parsedData);
    if (parsedData.length > 0) {
      setSelectedSpectrum(parsedData[0].name); // Выбираем первый спектр по умолчанию
    }
  };

  const handleSpectrumChange = (spectrumName) => {
    console.log('Selected Spectrum:', spectrumName); // Отладочный вывод
    setSelectedSpectrum(spectrumName);
  };

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="app-container">
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<WelcomePage />} />
          <Route
            path="/upload"
            element={
              <div className="upload-page">
                <h1>Оптические свойства тонких пленок</h1>
                <FileUpload onFileData={handleFileData} />
                {data && (
                  <>
                    <SpectrumSelector 
                      spectra={data} 
                      selectedSpectrum={selectedSpectrum} 
                      onSpectrumChange={handleSpectrumChange} 
                    />
                    {selectedSpectrum && (
                      <Chart data={data.find(spectrum => spectrum.name === selectedSpectrum)} />
                    )}
                  </>
                )}
              </div>
            }
          />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;




Как вы файл читаете? Откуда?

Можете из файла вставить несколько строк в вопрос без форматирования, что бы понимать, что и как у вас хранится

Я у себя написал такой же конвертор файла и проблем не увидел. Код(за мелким синтаксическим отличием) как у вас. На выходе получаю массив объектов вида [ { name: 'Spec1', data: [{1,2}] } , ]. Одна из возможных причин - вы не отсекаете первую строку, в которой нет данных. Может не все спец символы учитываете. Попробуйте в вашей функции парсере понатыкать console.log() и посмотреть, на чем все таки падает скрипт. И еще .split(/[,\s]+/) разбивает строку с цифрами на 4 значения, а не на 2 ожидаемых

@SwaD, благодарю вас! Скажите, чтобы мне решить следующий вопрос в данном проекте, из-за которого не работает код , мне необходимо отредактировать данный мой вопрос или создавать новый?

@SwaD, данные с текстового файла у меня отображаются в консоли сейчас. Но также есть ошибка "convertFile.jsx:3 Invalid file content type: object" .  И поэтому не дает использовать данные для выбора спектра и построения графика по спектру, я так понимаю. Мне же необходимо добиться  построения одного графика по одному выбранному спектру. В чём может быть ошибка, как Вы думаете?
Файлы convertFile и FileUpload обновлю в основном вопросе.

Ну у вас в ошибке даже строчка указана, где ошибка. Так же, натыкайте консоль логов

@SwaD, я обновил все файлы в первом своем сообщении, кроме App ( он не изменился )

Ну вот вы сами во 2й строке converfile делаете проверку, что данные это строка и сами выкидываете исключение, которое говорит вам, что пришел объект. Смотрите, где функция вызывается и что передаете
